# Minimum Requirements

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware, compatibility

This is a more granular/specific installation requirements for a specific laptop/software.

Linux NOOB here...

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS states minimum as:

- 2 GHz dual core processor or better
- 2 GB system memory
- 25 GB of free hard drive space
- Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

I have purchased an Acer Aspire One 532h Netbook which has

- Intel Atom N450 / 1.66 GHz processor
- 2 GB DDR2 PC2-6400 memory (I will be upgrading to)
- 250GB SSD (I will be upgrading to)
- Wireless Internet/Wired Ethernet

Hoping performance will be descent. Any thoughts? If this is "too much" for it to handle, any suggestions on best Linux? I want to install and run:

- Visual Studio Code
- GIMP
- Inkscape
- Scribus
- OpenShot
- Synfig
- Darktable
- Natron
- Ardour
- Master PDF
- LibreOffice
- Notepad++
- Chrome
- Firefox
- MonoDevelop
- Hearthstone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Recommend installing Ubuntu [MATE 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/518968#518968) + mate-netbook package.

Comment: This is a very specific/granular look at requirements and therefore, not a duplicate.

Comment: MonoDevelop has been discontinued in 18.04, but the MonoDevelop from 16.04 or 17.10 still works in 18.04. Visual Studio Code is gaining ground in 18.04 and also Microsoft's .NET Core has been released as a .deb file. specific and granular multiple topics will not save this question from being too broad, even if it blocks it from being an exact duplicate of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your (future) system is above Linux OS requirement except CPU speed. That would be good.

I think that your (future) laptop capability is also depending on application requirement as well. Please, check individual software package hardware requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about the CPU, but it appears the other upgrades are picking up the slack. No slowness outside of normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your system should work just fine.

Please go ahead and install. A hit and trial method of working is the best. Your confidence in linux will grow as to work on it all the more.